# How do I get accurate outputs when reading large amounts of data from a file?

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to use a for loop to read 100,000 int values from a file. I also want to add them up, find a min, and find a max. My code right now only reads correctly if I change the number of read values from 100,000 down to just 100. Even at 200 values, my code just skips data and doesn't give correct outputs. Can anyone see where my code could go wrong when reading for larger amounts of values? Thank You!

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int sum;
    int big, small = 0;
    string file;

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> file;
    ifstream inFile(file);

    for (long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        if (!(inFile >> number))
        {
            cout << "ERROR!";
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        inFile >> number;
        sum = sum + number;
        if (number < small)
        {
            small = number;
        }
        if (number > big)
        {
            big = number;
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << big << endl;
    cout << small << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, my input file is arranged like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
...
...
...
```

of course with other numbers

Comment: try this loop : ```long cnt=0;for(;inFile>>number;cnt++)```  see https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/

Comment: Your program reads 100,000 numbers and discards them then tries to read another 100,000 numbers and perform calculations on them. Unless there are 200,000 numbers in your file and you mean to throw away the first half your logic is incorrect. `big`, `mean`, and `sum` are also uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, your 1st loop is reading and discarding integers, and then your 2nd loop picks up where the 1st loop left off, rather than starting at the beginning of the file again. You should be using only 1 loop.

You are also not initializing your `sum` and `big` variables before entering the loop that increments them.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, sum, big, small;
    string file;

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> file;
    ifstream inFile(file);

    if (!(inFile >> number))
    {
        cout << "ERROR!";
        return 1;
    }

    sum = small = big = number;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        if (!(inFile >> number))
        {
            cout << "ERROR!";
            return 1;
        }

        sum += number;

        if (number < small)
        {
            small = number;
        }

        if (number > big)
        {
            big = number;
        }
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << big << endl;
    cout << small << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## EDIT notes

As @RemyLebeau pointed out, I made the mistake of not initializing `big` or `sum`, I fell a fool for the classic mistake of `a, b, c = 0` not initializing a or b, but only c.

Second, as also pointed out by Remy, I didn't realise that streams have the `operator!`, for checking if a failure has occurred on the stream.

With that in mind, here's my updated version, and the original below for posterity:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int sum = 0, big = 0, small = 0;
    string file;

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> file;
    ifstream inFile(file);

    for (long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        if (!(inFile >> number))
        {
            cout < "ERROR!";
            return 1;
        }
        sum = sum + number;
        if (number < small)
        {
            small = number;
        }
        if (number > big)
        {
            big = number;
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << big << endl;
    cout << small << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## ORIGINAL POST

First off, `sum` should be initialized to zero, since it's value is always determined by the result of an addition to itself.

```cpp
int sum = 0;
```

Second, in your first loop you're reading from the file, into a variable who's value is then discarded. This loop has the side effect of advancing the file pointer, so if you read 100000 values in the first loop, the second loop starts at the 100001th value in the file.

I don't really see any reason to do this in two separate loops, and I also don't see why you're checking the "result" of `inFile >> number`, since its [return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) is never null anyway:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int sum, big, small = 0;
    string file;

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> file;
    ifstream inFile(file);

    for (long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        inFile >> number;
        sum = sum + number;
        if (number < small)
        {
            small = number;
        }
        if (number > big)
        {
            big = number;
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << big << endl;
    cout << small << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*`sum` should be initialized to zero*" - yes, it should, and yet your code example is making the exact same mistake. `big` needs to be initialized, too.

Comment: "*I also don't see why you're checking the "result" of `inFile >> number`, since its return value is never null*" - the OP was using the stream's [`operator!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) to check whether `operator>>` had failed to read an `int` value, either because there was a non-int value in the file, or EOF was reached before 100,000 ints had been read. It is perfectly valid and recommended to validate input before using it. You should add that check to your answer. But, you are correct that the two loops can and should be combined into a single loop.

Comment: `small` needs to me initialized to something larger than 0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh my how did i miss that, i fell for one of the oldest mistakes in the book haha

Comment: @RetiredNinja good catch, I missed that, too.